# How to add class on click event in Aurelia?

Tags: css, aurelia

I'm new to aurelia. I'm looking to find the best method for adding classes on click events.

I simply want to click approve or request information, and then add a class to the corresponding "contact card". This class would change the background color.

I know it's probably simple, but I thought I'd look here for the best method.

Here's an image to what I've got:

[image: here's an image to what I've got]

Apologies for the wait, work has been a bit busy.

This is my first time posting on S.O., so I apologize for any expectations I'm not meeting.

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button class="btn btn-success col-sm-12" click.delegate="goodBoi()">
          approve contact
        </button>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <button class="btn btn col-sm-12" click.delegate="requestContact()">
                request information
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the element to be changed is named "list-group-item", containing the 
contact's details(code shown above).

```
<template>
<div class="contact-list">
   <ul class="list-group">
     <li repeat.for="contact of contacts" class="list-group-item ${contact.id === $parent.selectedId ? 'active' : ''}">
       <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:contact.id}" click.delegate="$parent.select(contact)">
         <h4>${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}</h4>
         <p>${contact.company}</p>
         <p>${contact.email}</p>
         <h6>${contact.approval}</h6>
       </a>
       <a route-href="route: contacts; params.bind: {id:contact.id}">
          <p>${contact.phoneNumber}</p>
       </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

```
goodBoi() {
    let result = confirm("Are you sure you want to confirm this contact?");
    if (result === true) {
      var standingShell = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
      //im hoping here I would add a class to the new variable//
      this.contact.approval = 'approved';
      this.save();

    }


  }
//confirms contact, changing color of approved contact//
//same thing here, just plan to give it a different color//
  requestContact() {
    let contactRequestText = "request sent to contact";
    this.routeConfig.navModel.setTitle(this.contact.approval = contactRequestText);
    this.ea.publish(new ContactUpdated(this.contact));
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what your current code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to set a CSS-class using Aurelia. Following I prepared an example gist:

Template:

```
<template>
  <h1>${message}</h1>

  <div class="form-group ${clicked ? 'red' : 'blue'}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button click.delegate="save()">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>

</template>
```

And the code class:

```
@autoinject
export class App { 
  @bindable clicked = false;

  save(){
   this.clicked = true; 
  }
}
```

https://gist.run/?id=425993b04a977466fa685758389aa2b4

But there are other, cleaner ways:

- using [`ref`](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#referencing-elements) in a [custom element](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements#custom-element-basics).
- [custom attributes](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-attributes#introduction).
- Include jQuery for using e.g. `$('#myelement').addClass()`